# Workaround for Subquery returns more than 1 error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Please help me out.
I'm creating a query to list down all the Principal (SLE_CODE = 11) and Interest (SLE_CODE = 23) Payment made by the client's loan (REF_NO field) in a columnar way.

I tried this code, but it returns an error of "subquery returns more than 1 row".

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TR_DATE, '%M %d, %Y'), SL_CLIENTID, REF_NO, SLE_CODE, (select amt from sldtl where REF_NO = 1958
AND SL_CLIENTID = 1782 AND SLC_CODE = 12 AND SLE_CODE = 23) as interest,
(select amt from sldtl sd where REF_NO = 1958
AND SL_CLIENTID = 1782 AND SLC_CODE = 12 AND SLE_CODE = 11) as principal
FROM sldtl
WHERE REF_NO = 1958
AND SL_CLIENTID = 1782 AND SLC_CODE = 12
```

Please refer to this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac32/2

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, which record from `sldtl` with `REF_NO = 1958` do you want?

Comment: Or move the subquery, and do a LEFT JOIN instead to get all values for that ref-no.

Comment: The record of the Principal Payment (SLE_CODE = 11) and Interest Payment (SLE_CODE = 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data and desired results would really help.  I'm pretty sure you want conditional aggregation.  Perhaps this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TR_DATE, '%M %d, %Y'),
       SL_CLIENTID, REF_NO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SLE_CODE = 23 THEN amt END) as interest,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SLE_CODE = 11 THEN amt END) as principal
FROM sldtl
WHERE REF_NO = 1958 AND SL_CLIENTID = 1782 AND SLC_CODE = 12
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TR_DATE, '%M %d, %Y'),
         SL_CLIENTID, REF_NO;
```

Comment: Woah! I've been working this code for days.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `case.. when` expression :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TR_DATE, '%M %d, %Y'), 
       SL_CLIENTID, REF_NO, SLE_CODE,
       case when SLE_CODE = 23 then AMT else null end as interest,
       case when SLE_CODE = 11 then AMT else null end as principal
  FROM sldtl
 WHERE REF_NO = 1958
   AND SL_CLIENTID = 1782 
   AND SLC_CODE = 12;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac32/16)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. This works too.. never did some case function.